# connection to postgres using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have user registration form with submit button. I want to connect to postgres database when user clicks on submit button.
Can I put this code in any other file and not in app.js. IF yes, how to call this code when user clicks on submit button and I am using express

Comment: Are you using any frameworks such as express?

Comment: Yes, I am using express ejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the code to establish a connection into a function in another file and export the function.  Import the function in your app.js.  Assuming your submit action makes an API call, assign the function to the route that handles the call.  Something like:

```
    app.post("/api/submit", functionToConnect)
```